# Tomcat permission denied to /home/ubuntu unable to GET,POST

Tags: java, apache, ubuntu, tomcat

I have currently deployed an application which used to work fine until i decided to extend /home/ubuntu volume. I attached another volume and copied all the contents of /home/ubuntu to the new volume and now the new volume is /home/ubuntu, I am able to login and all the permissions are fine.

My tomcat java application was working fine until I made this change, Now evey time I make a any of the POST,get,update calls my logs show

2019-06-10 16:55:08 ERROR ApplicationExceptionHandler:47 - MultipartException
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. /home/ubuntu/upload_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.tmp (Permission Denied)

Now I noticed this is a permission issue and just to test it i assigned -R 777 to /home/ubuntu, The application is able to respond to my REST calls, but as expected I am unable to login with the my private key because of the permission change thing, I just made it -R 755 and can login but the application cant respond to REST calls.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service file to see which user is running Tomcat. (usually user "tomcat")

Then run this command to give user "tomcat", group "tomcat" ownership of /home/ubuntu

`chown -R tomcat:tomcat /home/ubuntu`

https://gist.github.com/drmalex07/e6e99dad070a78d5dab24ff3ae032ed1

Comment: Is there any other way,  the /home/user directory must belong to the user it may not cause any issues now but say if I want to set up a chroot environment? not that I will but its rather uncomfortable to change the user's home directory to another user,.

Comment: Do you need to serve files from the home directory? Can you move them to the tomcat folder and serve them there?